# Delegate System.Action<dynamic,int> does not take `1' arguments

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, lambda, mono

I am trying to build the `PostgreSqlGeneration` code from [this repository](https://github.com/darionato/PostgreSqlMigrationSqlGenerator/) on Mono. Unfortunately I get an error I do not understand.

In the [PostgreSqlMigrationSqlGenerator](https://github.com/darionato/PostgreSqlMigrationSqlGenerator/blob/master/EntityFramework.PostgreSql/EntityFramework.PostgreSql/PostgreSqlMigrationSqlGenerator.cs) class the following method gives the build error "delegate System.Action does not take `1' arguments":

```
private void GenerateStatements(IEnumerable<MigrationOperation> migrationOperations)
{

    Check.NotNull(migrationOperations, "migrationOperations");
    DetectHistoryRebuild(migrationOperations).Each<dynamic>(o => Generate(o)); // <=here!

}
```

/edit The signature of the extension method is as follows:

[image: Signatures and error]

/edit 2. Here is the declaration for `Generate` method:

```
private void Generate(HistoryOperation migration)
{
    //migration

    Check.NotNull(migration, "historyOperation");

    using (var writer = Writer())
    {
        migration.CommandTrees.Each(
            commandTree =>
            {

                switch (commandTree.CommandTreeKind)
                {
                    case DbCommandTreeKind.Insert:


                        writer.Write(GetInsertHistorySql((DbInsertCommandTree)commandTree));

                       break;
                }
            });

        Statement(writer);
    }

}
```

I do not know why that happens since the `Each` only has a `dynamic` type and no integer one. But I am not that experienced with such lambda expressions. To learn more and to get the migrations to work I hope someone can explain why the error happens and how it can be fixed.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I put the signatures in the question.

Comment: Ok thanks. I don't see any reason why it would be asking for an `int` then.

Comment: It seems to take an extension method with a wrong signature?

Comment: What is `Generate`? Where is the declaration for that? Are you sure that it takes only one argument? It looks like it's possible it's actually that first overload of `Each()` that's being used here.

Comment: I'm 99% sure its breaking because its picking the wrong overload due to the `dynamic` argument, but I can't find any documentation explaining *why*.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I added the Generate function. And Bradley, perhaps it is because of Mono? [Insert BradleyMONO joke.]

Comment: @PatrickHofman You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I feel really bad that I cannot find **anything** that explains why this isn't working. If someone knows; please tell me. Google has failed here.*

Clearly the compiler is picking the wrong overload for `Each`. There are two in the library, one that takes an `Action<T>` and another that takes an `Action<T, int>`.

If you weren't using `dynamic` it would work fine (if I had to guess); but `dynamic` causes all sorts of weird issues; *plus* you are using Mono.

Since the compiler insists you use the other overload, the solution is simple enough. Just use it!

```
DetectHistoryRebuild(migrationOperations).Each<dynamic>((o, i) => Generate(o));
```

You took an extra parameter and didn't use it. Its not the end of the world.

You could also just explicitly instantiate the `Action` so the compiler doesn't have to choose:

```
DetectHistoryRebuild(migrationOperations).Each<dynamic>(new Action(o => Generate(o)));
```

Comment: Thanks. Now the error (on the same line) is `Delegate System.Func<dynamic,int> does not take \`2' arguments`...

Comment: @user2609980 Wow; sucks to be you. Please try my new suggestion and directly instantiate the action.

Comment: @user2609980 It should be `Each<dynamic>((o, i) => ...)`. There are two overloads for `Each` with one generic parameter. The one with two generic parameters is an overload you're not interested in.

Comment: @hvd I agree; except that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET No, `Each<dynamic>((o, i) => ...)` is not the `Each<dynamic>(o => ...)` the OP is using in the question. :)

Comment: Ha guys I changed it to (0, i) and now it says: `Dynamic operation cannot be compiled without Microsoft.Csharp.dll assembly reference`!

Comment: @hvd I realize that. The OPs problem is that the compiler appears to be selecting the two argument overload *even though he passed it a one argument function*. Like I said, I can't figure out why it would do that. I suggested this as a *workaround*.

Comment: Okay adding the reference made the code work. Unfortunately the next error is `System.NotImplementedException: MARS is not yet implemented.` Now I have to see how to put that off?  :/

Comment: @BradleyDotNET My point is that `Each<dynamic, int>` cannot *ever* select the `Action<dynamic, int>` overload because the *only* `Each<dynamic, int>` there is takes a `Func<dynamic, int>`.

Comment: @user2609980 Heh, I guess that's an improvement, that's completely unrelated to your current question, at any rate. :)

Comment: @hvd Ummm... that should match Action<T, int> which is the overload above the intended one. Am I just reading the picture wrong?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I see now that I did not yet implement this new `PostgreSqlMigrationSqlGenerator`. I have now and will let you known what happens.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET There are three overloads in total. (I'll ignore the `this` parameter.) `Each<T>(Action<T, int>)`, which has one generic parameter. `Each<T>(Action<T>)`, which also has one generic parameter. `Each<T, Ts>(Func<T, Ts>)`, which has two generic parameters. The OP wants the second overload, and you're attempting to help give the OP the first overload. Both the second and the first overload are specified by `Each<dynamic>`. Only the third overload can be specified by `Each<dynamic, int>`.

Comment: @hvd Oh *thats* what you were referring to. Okay; we're good now. I fixed the code. Thanks for pointing that out! Sorry for my blindness this morning.

Comment: No worries guys. New problem posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069403/how-to-circumvent-mars-is-not-yet-implemented-exception.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add a missing assembly reference of `Microsoft.Csharp.dll`. For some reason the error of a missing assembly reference became visible after changing the lambda signature from `i` to `(i,j)` as suggested by BradleyDotNET in his answer.